# List comprehension - decrement value by list of values

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy

I am working on mortgage loan calculator class which have to calculate installment and display detailed schedule with principal payment, interest payment and remaining principal. I have written all function I need but I have a serious problem with remaining principal. I'm trying with list comprehension:

```
class AnnuityMortgage(MortgageLoan):


def __init__(self, principal, duration, percentage, first_installment_date):
    super().__init__(principal, duration, percentage, first_installment_date)


def installment(self):
    return -1*(npf.pmt(self.percentage/12, self.duration, self.principal))

               
def installment_table(self):
    schedule = [self.first_installment_date + relativedelta(months = i) for i in range(self.duration)]
    period = np.arange(self.duration) + 1
    interest_due = -1*(npf.ipmt(self.percentage/12, period, self.duration, self.principal))
    principal_payment = -1*(npf.ppmt(self.percentage/12, period, self.duration, self.principal))
    principal_balance = [self.principal - principal_payment[i] for i in range(self.duration)]
    installment_timetable = pd.DataFrame({'Payment_date': schedule,
                                              'Principal_amount': np.around(principal_payment, decimals = 2),
                                              'Interest_payment': np.around(interest_due, decimals = 2),
                                              'Installment_amount':[self.installment() for _ in range(self.duration)],
                                              'Principal_balance': principal_balance
                                              })
    return installment_timetable
```

Do you think is it possible to calculate remaining capital using list comprehension? To be exact - I want to know how much capital is still to repay. For example I have 1000 USD loan, I pay 100 USD this month, so I have 900 to repay, and so on.